# How do I limit the number of ERC721 NFTs per account?

Tags: solidity, nft

I would like to restrict the number of NFTs any one address can own. How would you implement this in a Solidity smart contract? Say I have an ERC721 NFT contract, *Square.sol*:

```
      import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
      
      contract Square is ERC721 {
        
        constructor() ERC721("Square", "SQUARE") public {}
        
        string[] public squares;
        mapping (address => uint) public ownerSquareCount;
            
        function mint(string memory _colour) public {
    
          // No one should own more than one square
          require(ownerSquareCount[msg.sender] == 0, 'Each address may only own one square');
          
          squares.push(_colour);
          uint id = squares.length;
          ownerSquareCount[msg.sender]++;
          
          //Open Zeppelin ERC721 _safeMint function
          _safeMint(msg.sender, id);
               
          }
      }
```

I have tested the above code, but it still allows a single account to mint more than one Square NFT.

(I recognize that anyone can simply create multiple addresses as a work-around, but I'm hoping the effort of having to manage lots of addresses will limit the extent to which this would occur)

**EDIT**

I have found the solution. For some reason, the `ownerSquareCount` mapping does not work. Instead, you can use the `balanceOf` function, which is part of the ERC721 standard. If you change line 10 to:

```
require(balanceOf(msg.sender) == 0, 'Each address may only own one square');
```

It works like a charm, throwing an error if an account tries to mint more than one token.

I am only a beginner, but one piece of advice I can share: if you are building smart contracts off a standard (like ERC721 or ERC20), dig deep into those existing contracts. A lot of the functionality you are about to code is probably already done there. I found myself tidying up my NFT smart contract by simply deleting my functions and using the built-in ones.

Comment: You will also have to modify any other function that changes ownership like transfer, transferFrom.

Answer (score 1):

```
contract Square is ERC721 {

    constructor() ERC721("Square", "SQUARE") {}

    string[] public squares;
    mapping (address => uint) public ownerSquareCount;
        
    function mint(string memory _colour) public {
        require(ownerSquareCount[msg.sender] == 0, "You can't mint more than 1 sqaure"); //// difference, solution
        // No one should own more than one square
        require(ownerSquareCount[msg.sender] == 0, 'Each address may only own one square');
        
        squares.push(_colour);
        uint id = squares.length;
        ownerSquareCount[msg.sender]++;
        
        //Open Zeppelin ERC721 _safeMint function
        _safeMint(msg.sender, id);
            
    }
```

you just need to verify how much squares user have e.g. you just need to put a check at top which allows user to mint, if user haven't minted any nft then it'll allow user to mint.

difference mentioned in code