# Trying to limit number of times an NFT can be minted by a user/address

Tags: mint

I am attempting to write a contract that limits the number of times a user can mint my contract.  I have done a bit of research on my own and found [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94846/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-erc721-nfts-per-account) also asked and solved in this forum

I have attempted to follow that implementation, but I am still able to mint more than my USERLIMIT.  I'm new to writing contracts so I'm sure this is a newbie problem and appreciate any help.  Here is a a snippet of my code:

```
contract MZToken is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint256 MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;
    uint256 USERLIMIT = 5;
    mapping(address => uint)  public maxWalletMints;

    constructor() ERC721("MZToken", "MZTOK") {}

    /* 
    Creates a new transaction on the blockchain
    */
    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public  {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();

        require(tokenId <= MAX_SUPPLY, "I'm sorry.  The max all NFT's have been minted");
        require(maxWalletMints[to] <= USERLIMIT, "MAX NFT's per wallet and user reached.");
        maxWalletMints[to]+=1;
        
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }
```

My understanding is that the line showing `require(balanceOf(msg.sender) < USERLIMIT` should throw an exception if the user attempts to mint this contract more than 5 times, but that is not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was due to my ignorance of how Remix works :(. While I was compiling/deploying changes to my contract, I was not selecting the newly deployed version of the contract so I was always testing with the same version.  When using the Remix IDE you have to be sure you are working with the "correct" version of your deployed contract.  This was truly a newbie problem...Thanks to MadeInDreams and OliverD for the support on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample that will revert if you try to mint more than the max

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Token is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint256 MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;
    uint256 USERLIMIT = 5;
    mapping(address => uint)  public maxWalletMints;

    constructor() ERC721("MZToken", "MZTOK") {}

    /* 
    Creates a new transaction on the blockchain
    */
    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public  {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();

        require(tokenId < MAX_SUPPLY, "I'm sorry.  The max all NFT's have been minted");
        require(maxWalletMints[to] < USERLIMIT, "MAX NFT's per wallet and user reached.");
        maxWalletMints[to]+=1;
        
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override(ERC721,ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _beforeConsecutiveTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256,
        uint96 size
  ) internal override(ERC721,ERC721Enumerable) {}

     function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I have tried that, but I'm still getting the same result.  This is my updated code:

Comment: Are you able to mint more than one with this updated code?

Comment: Yes...I am able to mint more than the MAX_SUPPLY and more than the maxWalletMints.

Comment: Make sure that you compile your contract after you made your changes? This should clearly revert. Compile and redeploy.

Comment: not sure this is doing it.

maxWalletMints[to]++   you sould set it to a value. You might be incrementing here but not storing it

Comment: Yes...I am compiling and deploying.  I changed the contract to maxWalletMints[to]+=1; and it is still behaving the same way.  I can mint any number of contracts...no limits.  I updated the code above to show the current code.

Comment: Question....is this simply because I am also the owner and therefore the limits don't apply to me?

Comment: I can mint any number of contracts?? Not sure what your calling. Show me the call you make.

Comment: Sorry...it is one contract....but I can mint it any number of times.  I am using remix and invoking the safeMint function on my contract.

Comment: See my updated working answer. Added all the missing part and validated the code in remix

Comment: You should check actual successful NFT collection like Bored Ape and Azuki and see how they did it. Nothing better than demonstrably working code

Comment: Sorry...I’m sure your answer is correct, but I'm still not getting exceptions when
I exceed my thresholds.

Comment: Your not calling this contract.function? Double check where you make that call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your not calling this contract.function?"  I am testing the contract in remix and I am executing the safeMint functionl.